# wix burn bundle not appearing in "add or remove programs"

Tags: wix, burn

I have created a bundle installer using burn, and it is working correctly, I can install and unintsall using the exe, but it isn't appearing in the control panel "add or remove programs"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

  <Bundle Version="14.0" UpgradeCode="7adb5f07-fb5f-4348-8f28-c821bebdc15e">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            LogoFile="..\Installers\Graphics\banner.png"
            LicenseFile="..\Installers\Text\licence.rtf"
            ShowVersion="yes"
            ThemeFile="ClassicTheme.xml"
            LocalizationFile="ClassicTheme.wxl" 
            />

    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>

      <MsiPackage DisplayName="Install My Stuff" Permanent="no" Name="My Stuff" SourceFile=".\Kits\XL\Stuff.msi"></MsiPackage>
      <ExePackage DisplayName="Register Components" Permanent="no" Name="my custom stuff" SourceFile=".\Bin\RegAddIns.exe"></ExePackage>
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bundle doesn't have a name is my guess. You're missing several possible attributes in your `<Bundle>` tag. Usually I would include the Name, Version, Manufacturer, IconSourceFile, and UpgradeCode in the bundle definition. These are all used in the add/remove programs entry.